# Use sympy solve differential equation with initial condition and get an implicit result

Tags: python, sympy

Here is the question and what I got so far, but I do not know how I should go for the next to get C1.
`Solve the IVP (1/x + 2y^2x)dx + (2yx^2 - cos(y))dy = 0, y(1) = pi.` Give an implicit solution

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')

y = Function('y')

deq = diff(y(x),x) + (1/x + 2*y(x)**2*x)/(2*y(x)*x**2 - cos(y(x)))

ysoln = dsolve(deq, y(x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```py
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')
y = Function('y')
deq = diff(y(x),x)*(2*y(x)*x**2 - cos(y(x))) + (1/x + 2*y(x)**2*x)

# this leads to an error
# ysoln = dsolve(deq, y(x), ics={y(0): pi})

# so we do it our own way
ysoln = dsolve(deq, y(x))
C1 = solve(ysoln.subs(x, 1).subs(y(1), pi), 'C1')[0]
ysoln = ysoln.subs('C1', C1)
print(ysoln)
# Eq(x**2*y(x)**2 + log(x) - sin(y(x)), pi**2)
```

My version couldn't solve the equation in the form that you have so I had to restructure `deq` a bit. It probably just a little problem with all the division.

Note that this is likely will not work for every ODE. It worked now because one can solve for the unique solution of `C1` given the initial conditions. Also, in the future, SymPy might not use `C1` as the name of the arbitrary constant and functions such as `.subs('C1', C1)` will not work in that case.

As an interactive session though, the above method will work just fine.

Comment: Here is what i got, and it worked. and thanks for your help, a lot!! from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
y = Function('y')
deq = diff(x)*(1/x + 2*y(x)**2*x) + diff(y(x))*(2*y(x)*x**2 - cos(y(x)))
ysoln = dsolve(deq, y(x))
print('The solution is', ysoln)
C1 = symbols('C1')
y2=ysoln.subs({y(x):pi,x:1})
Csoln=solve(y2,C1)
print('C=', Csoln[0])
yx=ysoln.subs(C1,Csoln[0])
print('Solution is ',yx)